# Загрузка изображений в БД из интернета

Tags: python, mysql

В ходе проекта возникла необходимость загрузки изображений, полученных из интернета, в базу данных mysql. Разобрался с тем, как загрузить его, предварительно скачав на компьютер:

```
def insert_photo(url):
    download_photo(url)
    con = pymysql.connect('localhost', 'root', '****', 'vk_users_photo')
    with con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        data = read_file('C:/Users/ilsha/DataSet/input.jpg')
        query = "INSERT photos(photo) VALUES (%s)"
        cur.execute(query, data)
        con.commit()
    os.remove('C:/Users/ilsha/DataSet/input.jpg')
```

Однако такой подход не очень удобен. Хотелось бы загружать картинки в базу на лету, не скачивая их сначала на компьютер. Не могу придумать, как реализовать подобное, не смог найти ничего похожего в сети. Буду очень благодарен, если поможете.

Comment: Не хотите на диск - грузите в память... но без промежуточного получения файла хоть куда-нибудь ничего не получится.

Comment: @IlshatIbrahimov, что возвращает `read_file`? Байты?

Comment: @gil9red да, в базу затем записываю как Blob
def read_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        photo = f.read()
    return photo

Comment: @IlshatIbrahimov, тогда никаких проблем не должно быть. Делаете запрос к картинке по ссылке, в ответ получаете байты, добавляете их в базу тем же запросом. Например, для `requests` будет примерно: `import requests` + `rs = requests.get("https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/6244078?s=460&v=4")` + `cur.execute(query, rs.content)`. `rs.content` вернет массив байт, что является картинкой по ссылке, аналогичное вернуло бы `f.read()`

Comment: @gil9red Большое спасибо, это действительно работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
import requests
...

def insert_photo(url):
    con = pymysql.connect('localhost', 'root', '****', 'vk_users_photo')
    with con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        rs = request.get(url)
        query = "INSERT photos(photo) VALUES (%s)"
        cur.execute(query, rs.content)
        con.commit()
```